# How does comint-mode override beginning of line behavior? I want same functionality to eshell

Tags: evil, eshell, comint

My Emacs version is 24.5.1.

Comint-mode protects the prompt by somehow defining the beginning of line to start directly after the prompt regex. This works for normal motion commands like `move-beginning-of-line` and even evil-mode motions. For example I can kill the current input by calling `evil-change-whole-line` and leave the prompt on the same line intact.

Eshell-mode isn't derived from comint mode, and the `C-a` shortcut is overriden to eshell-bol, which takes the prompt into consideration. So by using normal Emacs shortcuts most things work, but trying to use the standard commands for movement like `move-beginning-of-line` yields unexpected results. So by using `evil-change-whole-line` I kill the whole line, when I only wanted to kill the input.

How does comint-mode protect the prompt and is it possible to implement the same behavior in eshell-mode?

Things I have tried but didn't bear fruit:

1. `comint-line-beginning-position` and `comint-bol`are defined in comint.el, but they aren't called when calling `evil-change-whole-line` or `move-beginning-of-line`.
2. I noticed some references to the `inhibit-field-text-motion` variable in comint.el. But it is `nil` in at least `shell-mode`, which is comint-derived.

Comment: Just a guess, but check to see if the prompt has the [read only text property](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dan's [comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13592/how-does-comint-mode-override-beginning-of-line-behavior-i-want-same-functional#comment20428_13592) helped me on the way. Comint achieves the prompt protecting functionality with text-properties. I can add the needed properties in eshell by evaluating.

```
(add-text-properties (point-at-bol)
                     (point)
                     '(inhibit-line-move-field-capture t
                       rear-nonsticky t
                       field output
                       front-sticky (field inhibit-line-move-field-capture)))
```

I'm still unsure how this specific combination of properties result in the functionality. But I was satisfied and added these properties to my custom prompt with `propertize`

Comment: "how [these] ... specific properties result in the functionality" - `field` and the "sticky" properties are explained in the linked manual page. `inhibit-line-move-field-capture` is not documented, but appears to be checked by `line-move-1` and `line-move-finish` in `simple.el`.

Comment: Thanks @npostavs for pointing me to `simple.el`! At least `line-move-1` is called for most of the evil-mode movement commands. It's a shame the `inhibit-line-move-field-capture` property isn't documented thoroughly,  because those functions are quite complex. I hope I have the time to study this further so I can propose a patch for eshell.