# Forbid inserting text before and after overlay

Tags: overlays

Is there any way to forbid insertion of text before and after specific overlay? (I mean on the same line that displays overlay.) *Forbid* means that either changes cancelled somehow or immediately reverted, or something like this. I'm ready to consider other options as well.

Comment: Perhaps there's a read-only property for the overlay?

Comment: @Dan, I don't see it [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Properties.html).

Comment: I believe this: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13592/how-does-comint-mode-override-beginning-of-line-behavior-i-want-same-functional should help.

Comment: @wvxvw, this is definitely useful link. I'll try to experiment and see if it does what I want. According to that answer I can set text properties of text from beginning of line till overlay and from end of overlay to end of line so that these regions are indeed "read-only".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed @Dan's advice helped me. My final solution is:

1. Mark all text beginning one character before overlay (that is including
   newline before it) and ending where overlay ends as read-only:

   ```el
   (set-text-properties (1- beg) end '(read-only t))
   ```
2. Now create overlay.
3. When it's time to remove overlay don't forget to remove `read-only`
   property as well:

   ```el
   (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
     (remove-text-properties (1- beg) end '(read-only nil)))
   ```